# How do we solve this rather simple ODE (Loewner equation with driving function $\sqrt t$)?

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations, conformal-maps

Remember the following result for the [Loewner equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loewner_differential_equation):

> If $\lambda:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then for all $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{\lambda(0)\}$ there is a uniqe $\zeta(z)\in(0,\infty]$ and a unique continuous $g(\;\cdot\;,z):[0,\zeta(t))\to\mathbb C$ with $$g(t,z)\ne\lambda(t)\tag1$$ and $$g(t,z)=z+\int_0^t\frac2{g(s,z)-\lambda(s)}\:{\rm d}s\tag2$$ for all $t\in[0,\zeta(z))$.

Now assume $$\lambda(t)=\sqrt t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0.$$ Since $$a\lambda\left(\frac t{a^2}\right)=\lambda(t)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\ge0\tag2,$$ we obtain $$ag\left(\frac t{a^2},\frac za\right)=g(t,z)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\zeta(z))\text{ and }z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\tag3$$ for all $a>0$. Inserting $a=\sqrt{t}$, we obtain $$\sqrt tg\left(1,\frac z{\sqrt t}\right)=g(t,z)\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in(0,\zeta(z))\text{ and }z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}\tag4.$$

> Now I've read that we can derive an ODE for $g(1,\;\cdot\;)$ from $(1)$ and solve this ODE to finally obtain an expression for $g(t,z)$. However, how exactly do we need to do this? And how do we determine $\zeta(z)$?

Let $h:=g(1,\;\cdot\;)$. Then we clearly obtain $$\sqrt th\left(\frac z{\sqrt t}\right)=z+\int_0^t\frac2{\sqrt s\left(h\left(\frac z{\sqrt s}\right)-1\right)}\:{\rm d}s\tag5$$ for all $t\in(0,\zeta(z))$ and $z\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$, but how do we find $h$?

Comment: using separation of variables on (4) I find solutions g(t,z) = At^((1-B)/2)z^B, where A and B are constants. Are these solutions unphysical?

Comment: @Derek Could you please also write out what you found for $A,B$?

Comment: @Derek Using a different approach (in a slightly more general setting), I was at least able to derive an identity: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4596589/47771.

Comment: g(1,1) = A; for example (DELTAg/DELTAz)(1,1) = AB, where DELTA/DELTA denotes partial derivative.

Comment: If A = 3 or -1 and B = 0, then equations (1), (2) are satisfied.